# Как определить тип файла?

Tags: c++

Пишу программу и мне нужно определять тип файла и дальше уже проводить операции над ним. Прошу заметить, не расширение файла, а его тип. (Медиа, файлы, архивы, код и т.д). Программа на С++. Желательно если можно это сделать через filesystem.

Comment: Нет какого-то волшебного решения. Есть десятки типов картинок, архивов, и вам нужно по содержимому файла проверять файл на каждый из этих типов. На линуксах есть команда `file`, которая пытается классифицировать файлы по туче встроенных правил: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/

Comment: Можно попробовать через libmagic (или как она там называется) - получаете mime файла и по нему определяете что с файлом можно сделать

Comment: Забавно, я сначала написал коммент про libmagic а потом посмотрел коммент что выше про то, что нет "волшебного решения". Магия ближе чем кажется))

Comment: ¿Почему бы не определять тип файла по расширению?